# jmeter - How to format json in body data (extracted from regular expression)

Tags: json, regex, jmeter

I'm trying strong text to extract json with regular extraction then post it in the next request body data with formatted json. For the json that I extracted, they are not formatted and I'm just wondering if there is any function or way to format it?

- Get request with regular expression extractor (extracted the bold section)

`{
    "groupedData": [{
                "key": "FirstItem",
                "count": 1,
                "groupID": 1,
                "items": [{
                    **"keyID": 97215,
                    "film": {
                        "name": xxxx,
                        "id": xxx,
                        "vendorID": 0,
                        "type": "PG",
                        "xxxx": xxx
                    },
                    "subGroups": null**
                }],
                "totalRows": 1
            }]
}`

- Post in the next request with extracted data (JSON data extracted from above request with regular expression is appearing as whole string and just wondering how can i format in this body data?)

`{
    "keyID": 123,
    "name": "SYSGEN",
    "period": {
        "keyID": 427,
    },
    "periodID": 427,
    "items": [{
        **${JSON}**
        }],
        "group": 0,
        "selRow": false,
        "rowId": 1,
        "$rowState": {
            "invalid": false,
        },
        "XXXX": XXXX,
    }],
    "ZZZZZZ": "ZZZZZ"
}`

Comment: could you mention which part you want to extract?

Comment: please provide the full get request response and also mention which portion you want / tried to extract form that response.

Comment: Thanks for you reply and sorry for late response. I was trying to extract info in ** data here **. Resolved my issue with answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the JSON using [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black), i.e.

1. If you have a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) `foo` where the extracted JSON data is stored and refer to it as `${foo}` in the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)
2. Replace your `${foo}` variable reference with the following function:

   ```
   ${__groovy(groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint(vars.get('foo')),)}
   ```
3. That's it, the above Groovy expression will format the JSON which lives in `${foo}` JMeter Variable

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Groovy function fixed up nicely for me in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get response text between given boundaries use [Boundary Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor):

Left Boundary:

```
  "items": [{
```

Right Boundary:

```
 }],
```

[image]

You can also test it using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)

> The Boundary Extractor Tester only works for text responses. It shows the plain text in the upper panel. The "Test" button allows the user to apply the Boundary Extractor query to the upper panel and the results will be displayed in the lower panel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and will bear it in mind for boundary extractor for future use.